# Create a for Loop to delete duplicates and to export them as csv from different columns of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, duplicates

Hey everybody currently I have a dataframe in R with 200 columns, what I want to do is to delete every duplicate in every column and then store each separate column as a .csv.

I've worked around with the following:

`df` is my dataframe

```
unique_Data_1<-as.data.frame(unique(df[, 1]))
unique_Data_2<-as.data.frame(unique(df[, 2]))
unique_Data_3<-as.data.frame(unique(df[, 3]))
unique_Data_4<-as.data.frame(unique(df[, 4]))
unique_Data_5<-as.data.frame(unique(df[, 5]))
unique_Data_6<-as.data.frame(unique(df[, 6]))#..........etc
unique_Data_200<-as.data.frame(unique(df[, 200]))
```

an then to save them

```
write.csv(x = unique_Data_1, file = "unique_Data_1.csv")
write.csv(x = unique_Data_2, file = "unique_Data_2.csv")
write.csv(x = unique_Data_3, file = "unique_Data_3.csv")
write.csv(x = unique_Data_4, file = "unique_Data_4.csv")#....etc
write.csv(x = unique_Data_200, file = "unique_Data_200.csv")
```

I know that working with a for loop would be better,  but I'm new to R and can't seem to find a working solution. I'd appreciate any insight on this.

Greetings,

EdgarH

Comment: With 2 loops: `myList <- lapply(df, unique); for(var in seq_along(myList) write.csv(myList[[var]], file=paste0("<path>/", names(myList)[i], ".csv")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#' I'll be using plyr / dplyr in this example
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

#' My test data to mimic yours
#' 
test_df <- data.frame(lapply(1:200, function(i){
  sample(1:100, 200, TRUE)
}), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% (function(x){
  colnames(x) <- 1:200
  x
})


#' Data frame of 200 rows and 200 columns for testing
> dim(test_df)
[1] 200 200

#' To show that each column has varying unique lengths for test purposes
#' 
> sapply(test_df,function(i){
    length(unique(i))
  }) %>% head

1  2  3  4  5  6 
90 81 82 87 87 90 

#' Create a directory in our working directory to hold the newly generated 
#' files.
> dir.create('u_cols')

#' This is an empty directory in our working directory now
> list.files('u_cols', full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
character(0)


#' 1) Iterate through each column and first filter to only unique values;
#' 2) Create a new file name with the columns vector position/name;
#' 3) Write the unique data.frame to a new file inside your created folder
lapply(colnames(test_df),function(i){

  # Create a new data frame with dimensions of N(rows) = length of unique values x 1(col)
  uni_col_df  <- data.frame(
    unique(test_df[[i]]), 
    row.names = NULL, 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

  # Set the column name of the original data frame to that of the subsetted new data frame
  colnames(uni_col_df) <- i

  #  Using the column name, which in your case is the same value as the iteration
  # the loop is on, create a new file path which will contain the uniquely 
  # subsetted data. 
  #  
  #  To learn more about the function and c-style formatting we're using see: 
  #  ?sprintf or ?formatC
  new_file <- sprintf('u_cols/unique_data_%d.csv', as.numeric(i))

  # Write the unique column data frame to the new file path
  write.csv2(uni_col_df, file = new_file, col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
})


new_files <- list.files('u_cols', full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
#' Check our newly created directory for the iterated files we just created
#' in the loop
#' 
> length(new_files)
[1] 200

#' For clarity and accuracy let's check our results by reading the data from the 
#' new files, and comparing with the columns of our original data frame.
#' 
#' So first i'll build a parse/index table so I can relate the files to the columns
#' more readily. What I mean is I want a data frame that will result in the name
#' of each file in the directory as the first column, and in the second column
#' I want the number that corresponds to the column in our test data itself

new_files_idx <- data.frame(files = new_files, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(
    col_n = as.numeric(
      gsub("(\\w+)/(\\w+)_(\\w+)_|\\.csv", "", files)
    )
  ) %>% arrange(col_n)

> head(new_files_idx)
                     files col_n
1 u_cols/unique_data_1.csv     1
2 u_cols/unique_data_2.csv     2
3 u_cols/unique_data_3.csv     3
4 u_cols/unique_data_4.csv     4
5 u_cols/unique_data_5.csv     5
6 u_cols/unique_data_6.csv     6


#' Take a sample set of 12% or in this case 24 rows of the file index table we 
#' built
samp_test <- sample_frac(new_files_idx, 0.12)

> head(samp_test)
                         files col_n
49   u_cols/unique_data_49.csv    49
31   u_cols/unique_data_31.csv    31
23   u_cols/unique_data_23.csv    23
95   u_cols/unique_data_95.csv    95
154 u_cols/unique_data_154.csv   154
4     u_cols/unique_data_4.csv     4

#' Last step is to ensure that all of the values stored in each of our newly created
#' files correspond to the unique values in the data set that exists in our 
#' working environment. So we do this by:
#' 
#' 1) Iterate through each for of the index table we created that contains a 
#'     sample set of the records made up of the file-path and column number
#'     the data corresponds to
#'     
#' 2) Read the data from the file and store to a variable in our loop 'dat_from_file'
#' 
#' 3) Ensure the data stored in the file is identical the the unique data in the 
#'     corresponding column of the original data set
#'     
#' 4) Check that all of the test evaluate to true
#' 
#' 5) Build an output table that corresponds with the sampled file indexes ,
#'    corresponding column number that was checked for validity, and 
#'     the results of the logical tests run in the iteration

run_checks <- adply(1:nrow(samp_test), 1, function(i){
  # For ref sake in the first iteration the file path being read would be :
  # u_cols/unique_data_49.csv
  dat_from_file <- read.csv2(samp_test$files[[i]], 
                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                             header = TRUE)

  # The numeric values contained in the file we just read in
  dat_vals <- as.numeric(dat_from_file[[1]])

  # This would be the unique numeric representation of values stored in the 
  # original data set as called by samp_test$col_n[[i]] which is [49] 
  env_vals <- as.numeric(unique(test_df[, samp_test$col_n[[i]]]))

  # Are they precise matches?
  identical(dat_vals, env_vals)
}) %>% cbind(., samp_test, row.names = NULL) %>%
  select(file = 3, 4, is_dentical = 2)


#' Our returned data validations
> head(run_checks)
                        file col_n is_dentical
1  u_cols/unique_data_49.csv    49        TRUE
2  u_cols/unique_data_31.csv    31        TRUE
3  u_cols/unique_data_23.csv    23        TRUE
4  u_cols/unique_data_95.csv    95        TRUE
5 u_cols/unique_data_154.csv   154        TRUE
6   u_cols/unique_data_4.csv     4        TRUE

#' Do they all return TRUE for identical?
> all(run_checks$is_dentical)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really useful!